# React Native map doesn't change width when rotate

Tags: react-native, google-maps

I have implemented google map accurately using react native. When I load the map in portrait mode it looks perfect. Then, when I rotate the phone to landscape mode map's width is still the same and doesn't change the width according to the screen width although I have coded it to work responsively.

[image]

[image]

But the problem is, when I load the map screen in the app in landscape mode map's width is perfectly fit into the screen with an increased width. But then when I rotate the phone into portrait mode, Map doesn't decrease it's width and I cannot see half of the map as shown in the below images.

[image]

[image]

Looks like map doesn't change it's width realtime. Have to load again to change the width.

My code is given below.

```
<View style={[styles.mapSubContainer, { width: this.state.width }]}>
    <MapView style={styles.mapStyle}
        initialRegion={{
            latitude: this.state.latitude,
            longitude: this.state.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.1,
            longitudeDelta: 0.1,
        }}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        onPress={this.onMapPress.bind(this)}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        followsUserLocation={true}
        showsMyLocationButton={true}
        showsCompass={true}
        showsTraffic={true}
        toolbarEnabled={true}
        onMapReady={() => this.setState({ width: width - 1 })}
    >
        <Marker draggable
            coordinate={{
                latitude: this.state.latitude,
                longitude: this.state.longitude,
            }}
            onDragEnd={(e) => this.setState({ x: e.nativeEvent.coordinate })}
        />
        <Circle
            center={{
                latitude: this.state.latitude,
                longitude: this.state.longitude,
            }}
            radius={this.state.radius}
            fillColor='rgba(253, 48, 4,0.5)'
            strokeColor='rgba(253, 48, 4,1)'
        />
    </MapView>
</View>

const styles = {
    mapSubContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 350
    },
    mapStyle: {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 30,
        height: 350
    }
}
```

Any solution for this would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you reassign `width` when orientation changed?

Comment: No. I didn't change the code

Comment: So that's why the view won't update when orientation changed. You could use https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation to detect orientation update, then update map's width and height